# EE GeoFinder plus EE Categories

Tags: ee2, categories

So I'm trying to assign a class via {category_url_title} inside of a {exp:geofinder:location_results} tag. The problem is now I have 2 loops. I tried several things like using {categories} tag pair by itself in the geofinder tag as well as a tagpair inside of a channel:entries tag. However, I still get similar, incorrect results. Chris Barrett/Mighty Big Robot doesn't seem to be offering much support on their site lately so I thought I would try here.

```
{exp:geofinder:location_results 
channel="business" 
status="not closed" 
geoquery="{embed:address}" 
radius="{embed:radius}" 
latitude="{business_lat}" 
longitude="{business_lng}" 
distance_mode="miles" 
limit="10"
}

    {exp:channel:categories 
    entry_id="{entry_id}" 
    show_empty="no" 
    channel="business" 
    status="not closed"
    limit="1"

    }

        <a href="/businesses/{url_title}" class="{category_url_title}">{title}</a>

    {/exp:channel:categories}

{/exp:geofinder:location_results}
```

Result:

NIXONMEDIA

NIXONMEDIA

TJ ROCKWELLS

TJ ROCKWELLS

LUCKY DUCKS

LUCKY DUCKS

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The [Channel Categories tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html) is *not* for listing the categories associated with an entry. It is for listing all of your categories.

You'd need to do this instead:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}" dynamic="no" channel="business" status="not closed" limit="1" disable="member_data|pagination|custom_fields"}
    {categories backspace="2"}<a href="{path="businesses/index"}" class="{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a>, {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This *should* work when directly nested like this, but if not you may have to place all that in an embedded template, and pass the `entry_id` as an embed parameter.

Comment: Hey Derek - As mentioned I tried the {categories} pair like you have above and when I do this it only returns 1 result (it should return 3).What I'm trying to do is return the category associated with the geofinder result and apply that via category_url_title. I think the problem lies in the geofinder plugin's limitations.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Actually, looking at Geofinder's docs, the `{categories}` tag pair should work natively. Have you tried including the tag pair directly inside the Geofinder Location Results loop (without an additional Channel Categories or Chanel Entries tag)?

Comment: This renders 1 result (instead of 3):

`{exp:geofinder:location_results 
channel="business" 
status="not closed" 
geoquery="{embed:address}" 
radius="{embed:radius}" 
latitude="{business_lat}" 
longitude="{business_lng}" 
distance_mode="miles" 
limit="10"
}
{categories}
    <a href="{embed:url}" class="{category_url_title}">{title}</a>
    {/categories} 
    
{/exp:geofinder:location_results}`

Comment: And you are positive that the entry in question has three categories assigned in the control panel?